# How to call rails method from view on button or link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view, controller

Basically, I'm trying to have a rails method execute when the user clicks on a link (or a button or some type of interactive element).

I tried putting this in the view:

```
<%= link_to_function 'Add' , function()%>
```

But that didn't seem to work. It ended up simply calling the function without a user even clicking on the "Add" link.

I tried it with link_to as well, but that didn't work either. I'm starting to think there isn't a clean way to do this. Anyway, thanks for your help.

PS. I defined the method in the ApplicationController and it is a helper method.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because when user clicks on button he is using his computer. And the rails code is in the server. You need to provide a mean to inform the rails server about this click event

**maybe what you are looking is Ajax?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The view and the controller are independent of each other. In order to make a link execute a function call within the controller, you need to do an ajax call to an endpoint in the application. The route should call the ruby method and return a response to the ajax call's callback, which you can then interpret the response.

As an example, in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Add', '#', :onclick => 'sum_fn()' %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    function sum_fn() {
        /* Assuming you have jQuery */
        $.post('/ajax/sum.json', {
             num1: 100,
             num2: 50
        }, function(data) {
             var output = data.result;
             /* output should be 150 if successful */
        });
    }
<% end %>
```

In your `routes.rb` add a `POST` route for your ajax call endpoint.

```
post '/ajax/sum' => 'MyController#ajax_sum'
```

Then suppose you have a MyController class in `mycontroller.rb`. Then define the method `ajax_sum`.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    # POST /ajax/sum
    def ajax_sum
        num1 = params["num1"].to_i
        num2 = params["num2"].to_i
        # Do something with input parameter and respond as JSON with the output
        result = num1 + num2

        respond_to do |format|
              format.json {render :json => {:result => result}}
        end
    end
end
```

Hope that hopes!

Comment: I think you have to use parens to call the function: `:onclick => 'sum_fn()'`.  Right?

Comment: Fixed thanks! Using `onclick` is probably not the best way of registering a click handler. It should instead be registered with Javascript, but for the purposes of demonstration, I think this is enough.

Comment: Thanks but you're missing a closing bracket on the post function.